# Is there a simple way to grab the first line from a file with helm?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I am attempting to create a kubernetes ConfigMap with helm, which simply consists of the first line within a config file. I put my file in `helm/config/file.txt`, which has several lines of content, but I only want to extract the first. My first attempt at this was to loop over the lines of the file (naturally), but quit out after the first loop:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: one-line-cm
data:
  first-line:
    {{- range .Files.Lines "config/file.txt" }}
    {{ . }}
    {{ break }} # not a real thing
    {{- end }}
```

Unfortunately, `break` doesn't seem to be a concept/function in helm, even though it is within golang. I discovered this the hard way, as well as reading about a similar question in this other post: [Helm: break loop (range) in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60966946/helm-break-loop-range-in-template)

I'm not stuck on using a loop, I'm just wondering if there's another solution to perform the simple task of extracting the first line from a file with helm syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
I've determined the following is the cleanest solution:

```
.Files.Lines "config/file.txt" | first
```

(As a side note, I had to pipe to `squote` in my acutal solution due to my file contents containing special characters)

---

After poking around in the helm [docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/) for alternative functions, I came up with a solution that works, it's just not that pretty:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: one-line-cm
data:
  first-line: |
    {{ index (regexSplit "\\n" (.Files.Get "config/file.txt") -1) 0 }}
```

This is what's happening above (working inside outward):

1. `.Files.Get "config/file.txt"` is returning a string representation of the file contents.
2. `regexSplit "\\n" <step-1> -1` is splitting the file contents from step-1 by newline (-1 means return the max number of substring matches possible)
3. `index <step-2> 0` is grabbing the first item (index 0) from the list returned by step-2.

Hope this is able to help others in similar situations, and I am still open to alternative solution suggestions.

Comment: Using a couple of the [Sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) functions, does `.Files.Get "config/file.txt" | splitList "\n" | first` work?  `regexFind "[^\n]*"` might also work (find the first block of characters that doesn't contain a newline).

Comment: @DavidMaze, yes, actually, both of those also work, and are a bit cleaner, thanks! For completeness, this is the entire latter solution you suggested: `regexFind "[^\n]*" (.Files.Get "config/file.txt")` . You mentioning `first` actually made me think of this solution (which I think I will mark as the "answer"): `.Files.Lines "config/file.txt" | first`. It's so obvious now, but took a lot of brainstorming. Thanks for the help :)